# Symfony2 Unable to generate URL although path exist

Tags: php, symfony

The controller:

```
namespace Main\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("login")
    */
    public function indexAction(Request $request){
        return $this->render('UserBundle:Login:login.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("login_check")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction(){
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction(){

    }
}
```

The view:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<form action="{{ path('/login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
{% endblock body %}
```

The error:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/login_check" as such route does not exist.") in UserBundle:Login:login.html.twig at line 3.

I've tried calling the login_check path itself and it is working, i've also replaced the path for the form to "login", it is also not working.

I've also tried clearing the cache and everything but its not working also.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Route from terminal:

```
 main_user_login_index       ANY    ANY    ANY  /login                            
 main_user_login_logincheck  ANY    ANY    ANY  /login_check                      
 main_user_login_logout      ANY    ANY    ANY  /logout                           
 main_user_register_index    ANY    ANY    ANY  /register                         
 main_admin_login_index      ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login/{name}               
 main_admin_login_logincheck ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/login_check                
 main_admin_login_logout     ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/logout
```

Comment: do the action names in the controller fits with the rules, with regard to the names in your route table?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `<form action="{{ path('/login_check') }}" method="post">`

Your route should be:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="/login_check")
 */
```

Comment: Hi there, the result is the same, Unable to generate URL.

Comment: Hi @KarlWong, did you use "php app/console route:debug" cmd to verify your available routes ? pls use this cmd to show your available routes and their names.

Comment: <form action="{{ path('main_user_login_logincheck') }}" method="post">

Comment: Thanks, i added a name to it. I thought that the path was the link.